# Highlight the unique VALUES column 1 (workbook1) compared to column 1 (workbook2)

Tags: excel, vba

*****EDITED WITH WORKING CODE******
While this code does work with another 2 workbooks, it is not working with the 2 workbooks I will show below.  I am trying to compare the values in the "Accounts" columns in 2 different workbooks.  For Workbook1.sheet1 highlight any account values that are in it, but not in Workbook2.sheet1. I purposely put a value (999999999) in WB1 to ensure validity and that at least that one should have come back highlighted.  Any ideas why it is not working?

Here are screen shots to see table structure:
**WB1**
[image: WB1]

**WB2**
[image]

And here is the VBA I wrote with help from an example I found.

```
Sub CompareCols()  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    Dim Rng As Range, RngList As Object, WB1 As Worksheet, WB2 As Worksheet  
    Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detailed Bill Info")  
    Set WB2 = Workbooks("FDG Accounts.xlsx").Sheets("FDG Accounts")  
    Set RngList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  
    For Each Rng In WB2.Range("A2", WB2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))  
        If Not RngList.Exists(Rng.Value) Then  
            RngList.Add Rng.Value, Nothing  
        End If  
    Next  
    For Each Rng In WB1.Range("A2", WB1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))  
        If RngList.Exists(Rng.Value) Then  
            WB1.Cells(Rng.Row, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 6  
        End If  
    Next  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

WORKING CODE:

```
Sub CompareCols()
'Disabling the screen updating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declaring variables
Dim Rng As Range, RngList As Object, WB1 As Worksheet, WB2 As Worksheet

'Setting values to variables declared
Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDG Accounts")
Set WB2 = Workbooks("Client Bill Info.xlsm").Sheets("Detailed Bill Info")
Set RngList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Loop to collect values that are in column A of this workbook
'that are not in column A of WB2
For Each Rng In WB2.Range("A2", WB2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not RngList.Exists(CStr(Rng.Value)) Then
        RngList.Add CStr(Rng.Value), Nothing
    End If
Next
'Iterate through results and highlight the cell with the unique value
For Each Rng In WB1.Range("A2", WB1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not RngList.Exists(CStr(Rng.Value)) Then
        WB1.Cells(Rng.Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        tmpStr = Rng.Value
        'MsgBox (tmpStr)
    End If
Next
Sheets.Add.Name = "myNewSheet"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: The first picture the Account Numbers are actual text that looks like a number and the second they are true numbers.  Text will not equal numbers.

Comment: One way would be to make them all strings.  Wrap all `Rng.Value` with `Cstr()`: `Cstr(Rng.VAlue)`  Then all will be strings.

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you know this because of the placement of the text in the cell being left-justified?  I keep attempting to use the "Format cells" from within Excel by clicking on the column and then selecting "number" as the format but it is not keeping it.  Can you enlighten me how to get over 40,000 cells to format properly?

Comment: Use Text-to-Columns.  It will convert it to General.  Just changing the format of the cell will not do it.  Number format does not effect strings.  There are many question/answers on this forum on how to convert numbers stored as text to numbers.

Comment: Thanks Scott!  I added the Cstr() to my range.values and got my desired result.